# Xamarin Forms, enable softkeyboard when bluetooth keyboard is connected in Android

Tags: xamarin, android-softkeyboard, inputmethodmanager

Currently, i'm working on my first project with Xamarin forms and android. I have a bluetooth barcode scanner paired with android device. So softkeyboard doesn't appear when it's connected. I tried many options what i found in the internet. Such as forced softkeyboard call from CustomEntryRenderer and other places. In some cases it's possible to handle in Language/InputMethods menu in Android, but not in all phones. Maybe i'm missing something, and called code from wrong place. The question is how to show softkeyboard, even when bluetooth keyboard is connected?

```
 InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = this.Control.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
        inputMethodManager.ShowSoftInput(this.Control, ShowFlags.Forced);
        inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Forced, HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

On my device, there are keyboard-related settings, one of which is "always show onscreen keyboard while a physical keyboard is connected". Switch this to "ON".

Apparently the default is to see the scanner not as "one of the keyboards" but "the only one", so an on-screen keyboard isn't needed. Which makes sense for a real keyboard, but not for a scanner.